# Ordering IHierarchicalEnumerable List c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a menu which is Heirarchical e.g.

Menu Parent A
- Sub Item A
- Sub Item B
Menu Parent B
- Sub Item A
Menu Parent C
Menu Parent D

etc

Its driven from a db and with each MenuParent I have an .Order int which I want to order the parent items.

My code is as follows;

```
        List<Menu> result = (List<MenuModel>)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
        var groupNames = result.Select(e => new Tuple<string,string,int>(e.menutitle, e.imageurl, e.ordernumber)).Distinct().ToList();

        int increment = 1;
        List<Category> lstc = new List<Category>();
        foreach (var item in groupNames)
        {
            _collection.Add(new Category(incrementforId, "0", item.Item1, item.Item2, item.Item3));
            List<string> lstItemTitle = result.Where(e => e.GroupTitle.Trim() == item.Item1).Select(x => x.ItemTitle.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();
            List<Category> lstclocal = (from ItemTitle in lstItemTitle select new Category(ItemTitle + increment, increment.ToString(), ItemTitle)).ToList();
            incrementforId++;
            lstc.AddRange(lstclocal);
        }

//ISSUE IS HERE
        _collection.GroupBy(x => x.Order);                
        _collection.AddRange(lstc);
```

Where;

```
public class CategoryCollection : List<Category>, IHierarchicalEnumerable {
```

However, I cannot seem to Order by the x.Order element? I have tried

```
var _collection = _collection.GroupBy(x => x.Order);
```

which is gives the error;

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'
>   to 'CategoryCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

and I have also tried.OrderBy which fails too?

ANy ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: What is the **type** of the `_collection` field?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry should have aded that. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: That's why you are getting the error. `GroupBy` definitely does not return `CategoryCollection`. But let see what are you trying to achieve. You want to order the items contained in the `_collection` (that you have added inside the `foreach` loop above) before adding the rest from `lstclocal`?

Comment: basically yes. I add in the parent items i.e. top most and want to order by the .Order held int he database (then I can just adjust orders from editing the db). Once I have this nailed I will implement a second orderby to order the subitems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you need is to replace this

```
//ISSUE IS HERE
_collection.GroupBy(x => x.Order);
```

with

```
_collection.Sort((x, y) => x.Order.CompareTo(y.Order));
```